# converting jpeg image to transparent png image

Tags: java, png

I have an image with text and white background. I want to retain the text, i want to create a png image with that text and a transparent background. Could anyone guide me.
Thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will guide you to what you want. You need to do something similar to following steps:

- Read the image,
- extract RGB values,
- create another image with ARGB

  BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
- And apply the operation similar to Image Thresholding to check the white background on image `bi`, If current pixel is white -> make that pixel transparant. Otherwise(for text image of other color) copy the pixel as it is.
- And finally save `bi` as PNG image using

  ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("C:\yourImageName.PNG"));

Do some research.

Comment: Thank u, I have posted my reply for that query.